# skip "#" regular expression Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to skip the comments using javascript. I can only get the reverse, meaning not skipping the comments. The following syntax:

```
#GSM settings\r\n   <----- Skip these
Apn internet\r\n
Pass \r\n
User \r\n
Pin \r\n
Dial *99#\r\n
KeepAlive 0\r\n
#ETH TEST\r\n                  <---- skip
Mac 00:60:37:12:34:56\r\n
EthIpv4 192.168.0.10\r\n
Subnet 255.255.255.0\r\n
Gwip 192.168.0.1\r\n
Autoip 0\r\n
```

Comment: Where is the JavaScript? Is that a string?

Comment: You can replace comments with an empty string, thus removing them, like so: `string.replace(/#[^\n]*/g, '')` or equivalent.

Comment: Skip when doing what? Show us your code, please

Comment: with this I grab the comments:/#.+\s*\r\n/g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understood 100%, if you want to match rows that are not starting with a "#", you can do it like this:

```
/^(?!#).*/
```

This matches only if after the start of the string there is not "#" directly following.

See it [here at Regexr](http://regexr.com?33ge7)

`(?!#)` is a [negative lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), that fails if there is a "#" following this position. Since it is after the `^` anchor, the whole expression will fail, if the first character is a "#".

If there can be whitespaces before the "#", you can add them like this:

```
/^(?!\s*#).*/
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?33ged)

Comment: perhaps for safety's sake include whitespaces in front of the hash or omit the `^`.

Comment: Actually, the "not" part can be done outside with `!` operator. No need for a look-around or matching the rest of the string.

Comment: how does the multiline /m affect the output?

Comment: @nikolas `/^(?!\s*#).*\r\n/gm` is the complicated version of stema's one without `m` parameter. If you specify this param, you need to stop at the linebreak, without you don't.

Comment: @nhahtdh mind to provide a regex for that? I never heard of a negative operator other than negative lookarounds or negative character classes.

Comment: @Christoph: I mean use if condition and test if the text is processed line by line. But your answer seems to be the only way if the text is multiline (which seems to be the case here since the OP said that it works after `m` flag is specified).

Comment: @nikolas, the `m` modifier changes the behaviour of `^` and `$` anchors, it makes them match on **Row** start and end. If you read your file row by row, you don't need this modifier. I used it only on regexr, because it has all the rows at once.